# Number of threads for git gc depending on repo size

Tags: multithreading, git, memory, git-gc

Can I use single-threaded compression in Git for large repositories and usual parallelized one for small ones? Like "pack.threads=1" if don't easily fit in momory and "pack.threads=4" otherwise.

As I heart somewhere, multithreaded "git gc" requires a lot memory and thrashes (or just fails) longer that singlethreaded.

I want it to work fast for small repos and don't fail on big repos.

Comment: Is the performance of this setting impacted by the repository size? I thought it was only related to number of cores?

Comment: @Arafangion, Multiple threads => much more memory needed (may be even proportionally). Lack of memory => swapping => slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure pack.threads per repository, but I doubt that there is a setting to do this automatically depending on the size of the repository.

Comment: OK, I forgot that it can be non-global option too.